# C# MVC model binding to indexed array on post

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Is it possible to model bind to posted broken indexed arrays ?

```
<input type='text' name='question[3]' value='answer to question 3' />
<input type='text' name='question[5]' value='whatever here' />
<input type='text' name='question[18]' value='a different ansewr' />

<input type='text' name='multiquestions[4][1]' value='question 4 part 1' />
<input type='text' name='multiquestions[4][2]' value='question 4 part 2' />
```

Ideally, I would like my model to be along the lines of (although typing this I can see that the sparse array keys would be an issue):

```
public class MyModel {
  public Dictionary<int,string> questions {get;set;}
  public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> multiquestions {get;set;}
}
```

and let the MVC model binder do the heavy lifting:

`public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model) {...}`

but it seems to only play nicely with non-broken indexes. I need the indexes as it is how I will put the data into th database.

I would rather not have a series of hidden fields describing the models, e.g. `<input type=hidden name='questions[0].Key' value='3' /><input type=hidden name='questions[0].Value' value='answer to question 3' />`

I have read  a [Hanselman blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) on the topic, which suggests writing a custom model binder if nothing out of the box works, but not sure where to start on writing a custom binder, and I am hoping that there is something that MVC can do "out of the box", or that somoene has solved this problem

Comment: AFAIK you need to pass either ViewBag or ViewData contains maximum amount of array index to apply on view input, iterate through 1 or 2 loops while providing either multiquestions[i][j] or questions[i] to print text input with indexed name attribute. The model should have array variable with same dimension to enable model binding.

Comment: Do not use a dictionary. Your model property needs to be `public IEnumerable<string> question { get; set; }` to bind to `name='question[3]'` etc. And to handle non-zero/non-consecutive indexers refer [this blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) but you do not need indexers. Just use `name='question` for all of them and it will bind fine

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, it turns out that not using int as the dictionary key is the trick.

Model binding will work as I expect using `Dictionary<string, string>` and `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`, and I need to parse the key to an int when I am on the server.

Answer (score -2):

May be you could check for count or null before accessing the value